# send a string to a cshtml partial page

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

have a cshtml partial I'd like to reuse.  I'd like it to only take a string so it is reusable, but can not seem to figure out how to send only a string.  If I send the Model it works, but then I have to specify my string variable.  Below is the partial call and the partial code.

Partial call:
    @model myModel;

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_CompanyInfo", Model.CompanyID)}
```

Partial code:

```
@model string;


<title>@Model</title>
```

UPDATED CODE

Partial call:

```
@model myModel

@{Html.RenderPartial("_CompanyInfo", Model.CompanyID)}
```

Partial code:

```
@model string


<title>@Model</title>
```

Comment: Run the full HTML of your partial view through an HTML parser. Also, as it is a partial view, you should not include `<!DOCTYPE>`, `<html>`, `<head>`, or `<body>` tags. Only the HTML that will be inserted into the other view.

Comment: It was just sample code i used as an example.

Comment: OK, but in the comment you left on MDDDC's answer, you said that your HTML is missing a ">". More information is needed, as that would lead me to believe you missed closing off a node, unless you're not escaping a `>` in a string somewhere.

Comment: it was a very cryptic error, but i needed to remove the ; from my @model lines

Answer (score 0):

```
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_CompanyInfo","your text here");}

@{Html.RenderPartial("_CompanyInfo", Model.CompanyID.ToString())}
```

Comment: I've tried that and i get this error in my event log: Message: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mysite\5f97d6c2\e3a94e94\App_Web__layout.cshtml.639c3968.6syhcytk.0.cs(32): error CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected

Answer (score 0):

why in your page there is all the html ?
in a partial is strange that you have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
....
```

**also remove the semicolon** in this way 
**@model string**

Comment: I just updated it, that part was not causing any issues, it was just sample code not a real partial.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.  I needed to remove the ; from the layout and partial @model lines.  I will update my code above.

Comment: There is no need to do that;

Comment: Please leave your code at the state it was that caused you to write the question. If you "fix" your code in the question, anyone else who has a similar issue will be completely lost.